# how to cancel command in GRUNT shell

Tags: linux, shell, hbase, apache-pig

This is probably a more general question: Many tools in linux have their own shells. In my case, I use pig and hbase. Sometimes when you execute a command in the shell, it returns a lot of results and I want to cancel it. Let's say for example you do cat 'a.txt' and that file is huge. What's the best way to cancel it without exiting the shell. If I press Ctrl+c it'll exit the shell.

Comment: Few Linux tools have their own *shell*. However, some are built above some scripting language, others have their own set of interactive commands.

Comment: what's your main intention?limiting the no of results or do you want this for each command?

Comment: I was talking about killing sth when you're at the program shell. Here's an example: 1) pig (which starts the shell) 2) run some useful commands (load stuff, manipulate data, etc) 3) cat a.txt (the file is huge and keeps dumping data to screen. I want to stop command (3) but not get out of pig shell.

Answer (score 1):

`kill <job_id>`
will kill a mapreduce job `with the specified id. It's not exactly what you are looking for but there is no easier solution that I know off.