# Cancel command in Grunt that hasn't been launched

Tags: apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

In Pig Grunt, if I make a mistake in my command (for instance not closing a '), it shows a new prompt until the command is fixed:

```
grunt> tmp = LOAD '/mapred/data;
>>
```

In the case above, adding '; would solve it, but sometimes the command is long and complex, and finding the culprit proves difficult.

Is there a way to cancel the current entry without exiting Pig altogether? I.e., not ctrl+C or ctrl+D?

Note: I know it's similar to this question [how to cancel command in GRUNT shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043805/how-to-cancel-command-in-grunt-shell), but in my case the command hasn't been launched yet.

Answer (score 2):

Corresponding to your example, I realized one way of exiting is to complete the line which is open due to the single quote. Therefore in this case I added the following in the next line and it quit with an error.

```
>> ';
```

Not sure if there is an easier way to do this, more so because the grunt shell is still not very developed. In any case, I hope there is a better workaround for this soon.

Comment: This option is already mentioned in the question, I'm looking for the general case when it's not obvious.